# Ubuntu unicode directory name starting with backslash renaming

Tags: command-line, rename, unicode

How can I rename a folder with the name `\316\234aintenance` under the Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Copy-pasting from `ls` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If there is just *one* directory that looks like that, you can use a wildcard:

```
mv *aintenance maintenance
```

This will rename anything suffixed with `aintenance` to use the value given. So long as there is just one record that meets this criteria, it will give you what you need.

Comment: I didn't try your solution but the command ```rename 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' *``` did the job

Comment: Be sure to write that up as an answer. It might help someone else who has a similar problem in the future 

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
rename 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' *
```

You can also try the solution @matigo suggested above

`mv *aintenance maintenance`